# Nested Generic Constraints: Constrain the T of a generic item inside a generic sequence extension that is constrained to that generic type

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift we can write extensions on generic items such as sequence:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : ObservableType {

}
```

This would guarantee the extension only applies to sequences of (in this case) RxSwift observables.

However if the element constraint is another generic can you then constrain that generic? e.g.:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : ObservableType where E : MyType {

 }
```

In the above pseudo code (that does not work) the intent is to say:

This extension should apply to sequences of Observable where the Observable is an Observable of type MyType e.g. [Observable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict `Iterator.Element` to types conforming to
`ObservableType` and then add another constraint for the associated type `E` of `Iterator.Element`:

```
protocol ObservableType {
    associatedtype E
    // ...
}

class MyType { }

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: ObservableType, Iterator.Element.E: MyType {

}
```

Comment: That's not quite the same though is it? that's two constraints on the sequence element? rather than one constraint that the element should be generic with a constraint on what that generic should be within that?

Or do you mean the second piece would be ObservableType.Element.E? (goes to try)

Comment: @Cargowire: The above code restricts the extension to sequences of observables with an associated type that inherits from MyClass. Perhaps I am overlooking or misunderstanding something – is this different from what you need? In which case would it not work as intended?

Comment: gah you're correct I was misreading the second constraint as just 'Iterator.Element' instead of 'Iterator.Element.E'!